# Use BeautifulSoup to get profile picture without class name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

when I learn BeautifulSoup library and try to crawl a webpage, I can limit the search result by limiting the attributes like: a, class name = user-name, which can be found by inspecting the HTML source.

Here is a success example:

```
    <a href="https://thenewboston.com/profile.php?user=2" class="user-name">
                                            Bucky Roberts </a>
```

I can easily tell

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'user-name'}):
```

However, when I try to get the profile photo's link, I see the code below by inspecting:

```
    <div class="panel profile-photo">
        <a href="https://thenewboston.com/profile.php?user=2">
            <img src="/photos/users/2/resized/869b40793dc9aa91a438b1eb6ceeaa96.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
```

In this case the .jpg link has nothing to refer to. Now what should I do to get the .jpg link for each user?

Comment: I've not used BS for a while though you can search the `div` (for which you know the class) and then take the first child of the first child (and get its `src`)

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your advise, I tried multiple times following ur advices. But I am very new to this and always get errors. Can you give me a line of code limiting the tag?

Comment: You should rather use @alecxe idea, it's way cleaner and more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `img` element parent elements to create your locator. I would use the following [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that would match `img` elements directly under the `a` elements directly under the element having `profile-photo` class:

```
soup.select(".profile-photo > a > img")
```

To get the `src` values:

```
for image in soup.select(".profile-photo > a > img"):
    print(image['src'])
```

Comment: Alecxe, thank you very much for your service. What do you think about regex I'm aware that it's slow.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic no problem. I think you are asking about regexes in the context of using it for HTML parsing. If this is the case, it is, generally speaking, a controversial topic and it's not trivial to come up with a generic answer. There is that famous topic that raises a lot of great points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Thank you for that, I did review it in few minutes but I'll sure take an in-depth (with notes) look when I'm free. I do feel like I have to come up with a generic answer because when I don't I see someone else do it in a simple manner and it crushes me :c haha, the Outstanding knowledge you've got is admirable, thank you again for your response.

Comment: @alecxe, hi man, I tried with `soup.select(".profile-photo > a > img")`. I got ValueError: Invalide CSS Selector: > img.   Then, I got rid of `>img` and tried `soup.select(".profile-photo > a")`. It starts to return  things like: `                                                Bucky Roberts    (which is the link.string)                                         
<a href="https://thenewboston.com/profile.php?user=2">
<img alt="" src="/photos/users/2/resized/869b40793dc9aa91a438b1eb6ceeaa96.jpg"/>
</a>`  I am wondering how to get the src link in the latter half? A way similiar to link.string

Comment: @Noob. you should not be getting the `ValueError` - the selector looks valid. Anyway, I've updated with an example on how to get the `src` values. Take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Yeah, it works. I realized in my code, I deleted the space before img. `>img` gives the error while `> img` works